# MassTransit and Azure Service Bus: EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration for all created subscriptions

Tags: .net-core, azureservicebus, masstransit, dead-letter, azure-servicebus-subscriptions

We configure MassTransit to use Azure Service Bus in this way:

```
                mtConfig.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, busConfig) =>
                {
                    busConfig.Host(new HostSettings
                    {
                        ServiceUri = new Uri(xxx),
                        TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateManagedIdentityTokenProvider()
                    });

                    busConfig.ConfigureJsonSerializer(ConfigureJsonSerialization);
                    busConfig.ConfigureJsonDeserializer(ConfigureJsonSerialization);
                    busConfig.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
                });
```

How can we set e.g. subscription properties like EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration for all the subscriptions created automatically by MassTransit?

Thanks,
Peter

**Update**

I've tried this (EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration), but the dead letter option isn't enabled on the subscriptions in the Azure Service Bus (we've deleted all the topics and subscriptions first, so that they were newly created):

```
            mtConfig.UsingAzureServiceBus((context, busConfig) =>
            {
                busConfig.Host(new HostSettings
                {
                    ServiceUri = new Uri(xxx),
                    TokenProvider = TokenProvider.CreateManagedIdentityTokenProvider()
                });

               busConfig.EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration = true;

               busConfig.ConfigureJsonSerializer(ConfigureJsonSerialization);
               busConfig.ConfigureJsonDeserializer(ConfigureJsonSerialization);
               busConfig.ConfigureEndpoints(context);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a class that implements `IConfigureReceiveEndpoint` (see [the docs](https://masstransit-project.com/releases/v7.1.6.html#iconfigurereceiveendpoint)) and in that function, pattern match the configurator to see if it is Azure Service Bus and set the properties. When registered in the container, MassTransit will run the class against each endpoint.

```csharp
class ConfigureMyEndpoint :
    IConfigureReceiveEndpoint
{
    public void Configure(string name, IReceiveEndpointConfigurator configurator)
    {
        if(configurator is IServiceBusReceiveEndpointConfigurator sb)
        {
            sb.EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: ok thanks, I'll try that out. Any ideas, why setting EnableDeadLetteringOnMessageExpiration = true does not work (see my updated question)?

Comment: If the queue already exists, it isn't going to change the value.